# Creating new layer in Caffe

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, gradient-descent

I use [caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) for my deep learning.
To create a new layer for caffe, I need to

(1)add layer to proto/caffe.proto to update the next available ID

(2)make layer createable by adding it to layer_factory.cpp

My queries are what is the purpose new ID in caffe.proto and the functionality of createable in layer_factory.cpp.

There are some layers not included as createable in layer_factory.cpp. What is the difference between those layers included and not included in layer_factory.cpp.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to add a new layer to caffe, please follow the instruction in [wiki/Development](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/Development).
You'll see there that you don't need to change `layer_factory.cpp`, but rather add two macros `INSTANTIATE_CLASS` and `REGISTER_LAYER_CLASS` in your cpp file.

Regarding `caffe.proto`: you only need to change there if you want your layer to have a specific `my_layer_param` message. If your layer re-use params of existing layers, you don't need to change `caffe.proto` at all.